# Iterating through data members of an object in a vector

Tags: c++, vector

I'm trying to achieve a sort of relation between 2 classes with an `id` attribute. `teamId` in `SoccerTeams` class must be same as the `directorId` of a director in `managing_directors` class so as to assign a managing director to a soccer team.

Both classes have a vector `teams` and `man_dirs` respectively.

```
class SoccerTeams {
    string teamName;
    int teamId;
    friend class managing_directors;
 public:

    //teams vector
    vector<SoccerTeams> teams;

    void addTeam(string name, int id) {
        SoccerTeams newTeam(name, id);
        teams.push_back(newTeam);
    };

    SoccerTeams(){};
    SoccerTeams(string teamName, int id){
        teamName = teamName;
        teamId = id;
    };
    ~SoccerTeams(){};
};


//managing directors of a soccer team
class managing_directors : public SoccerTeams, public people {
    int directorId;
 public:
    //man_dirs vector
    vector<managing_directors> man_dirs;

    managing_directors(int num_of_managers, int avg_age);
    managing_directors(){};
    ~managing_directors(){};
    void addDirector(string name, char sex, int age, int id) {
        managing_directors newDirector;
        newDirector.name = name;
        newDirector.sex = sex;
        newDirector.age = age;
        newDirector.directorId = id;                        
        man_dirs.push_back(newDirector);
    };
```

I tried making a function to check team id in managing_directors class as follows.

```
int idChecker(int id) {
    for (vector<SoccerTeams>::const_iterator i = teams.begin(); i != teams.end(); ++i) {
        if(i -> teamId == id)
            return 1;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

But the function always returned 0, which I believe is because it is not checking the same instance of teams vector created in the main function, since when I tried printing this `teams` vector inside `managing_directors` class, it was empty. Is it possible to make the `teams` vector global?
Is this the correct approach to solve this problem?

Definition of people class inherited in `managing_directors`(just in case)

```
class people {
    string name;
    char sex;
    int age;
    bool under_auth;
    int auth_level;
    friend class managing_directors;
 public:
    people(){};
    ~people(){};    
    virtual int get_age(){ return this->age; }; 
};
```

**UPDATE:**

I fixed the loop as given in one of the answers, but I don't think that was the issue, since the function still returns 0. I tried using cout to try and print all the ids and I got nothing in the output, it was empty.

I did something like this

```
int idChecker(int id) {
    for (vector<SoccerTeams>::const_iterator i = teams.begin(); i != teams.end(); ++i) {
        cout << i - > teamId << endl; //test code
        if(i -> teamId == id)
            return 1;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Use `.cbegin()` and  `.cend()` for `const_iterators` .(C++11)

Comment: Why does managing director class inherit from soccer team ?

Comment: On your update:  probably a sign that you are not populating the vector correctly, since the advice was correct given the information you previously provided.   You need to show code which does that.   More generally, though, provide an [mcve] and be specific in your question.    Don't doll out bits of information iteratively to get people to solve one problem for you after another.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your loop is wrong.  In

```
for (vector<SoccerTeams>::const_iterator i = teams.begin(); i != teams.end(); ++i) {
    if(i -> teamId == id)
        return 1;
    return 0;
}
```

If the first `i` does not match then you immediately return 0.  What you need to do is move that `return 0;` out of the for loop so you only return 0 when the loop does not find a match.  That gives you

```
int idChecker(int id) {
    for (vector<SoccerTeams>::const_iterator i = teams.begin(); i != teams.end(); ++i) {
        if(i -> teamId == id)
            return 1;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

You can also simplify this using ranged based for loop like

```
int idChecker(int id) {
    for (const auto& e : teams)
        if(e.teamId == id)
            return 1;
    return 0;
}
```

You could also use [`std::any_of`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/all_any_none_of) and a [lambda](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/lambda) like

```
int idChecker(int id) {
    return std::any_of(teams.begin(), teams.end()
        [=](const auto& e) { return e.teamId == id; });
}
```